# JMH установка benchmark mode

Tags: java

У аннотации *@BenchmarkMode()* есть несколько значений, их назначение для меня весьма туманно. 
Подскажите, правильно ли я их понял :

- Mode.Throughput - тест-метод запускается несколько раз в течение заданного ограниченного времени(итерация). Измеряется сколько полных раз он успел выполниться(если не уложился во время, то последнее выполнение, видимо не учитывается)
- Mode.AverageTime - тест-метод запускается так же, но измеряется среднее время выполнения(снова последнее выполнение может отбросится из расчетов)
- Mode.SampleTime - это вообще не понятно, дано только какое-то дурацкое объяснение в доках
- Mode.SingleShotTime - запуск 1 раз и замер времени выполнения
- Mode.All - прогон всех типов и результат по каждому отдельно
  так же моды можно сочетать как угодно

кроме того, с помощью *@OutputTimeUnit(TimeUnit.SECONDS)* можно задать время 1й итерации, в данном случае - секунду

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Mode.Throughput/Mode.AverageTime` - я думаю, не успевший тоже учитывается (иначе если один прогон не влезает в отведённое время, то вы бы вообще результатов не получили). Просто усредняется не за отведённое время, а за фактически потраченное. Например, если у вас на итерацию отведена секунда, а тест выполняется примерно 0.6 секунд, то общее время на итерацию будет по факту 1.2 секунды и результат усреднится по двум прогонам.

`Mode.SampleTime` не пользовался. Как я понимаю, итерация разбивается на случайные куски, и замеры ведутся по кускам отдельно, и это помогает собрать дополнительную статистику - персентили (например, 1% худших времён и т. д.)

`Mode.SingleShotTime` - полезно бывает вкупе с `@Measurement(batchSize = xxx)` для запуска фиксированного числа итераций.

`@OutputTimeUnit(TimeUnit.SECONDS)` - это единица времени для отображения результатов, а не длина итерации. Для длины итерации надо ставить `@Measurement(time = 500, timeUnit = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)`, например, для 500 мс. И соответствующие опции у `@Warmup` для разогревочных итераций.